# PostgreSQL Filter Problems on Heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, heroku, filter

I am a newbie to Ruby and have expirienced a problem with a PostgreSQL Database on Heroku.

So, I have written a little app which stores time entries: http://timekeper.herokuapp.com/

Now i have deployed the application to heroku and connected it with a Postgre Database.

**Expected Behaviour**

After pressing the "Speichern"-Button an AJAX Request is fired an should update the table and the right diagram.

**Problem**

The AJAX Request is being responsed but seems to be empty there is not data in it.

**What have i tried?**

The logs (´heroku logs´) doesnt contain anything suspicious.

I have tracked down the problem to one Command:

```
data = DateTime.now
time_a = DateTime.new(data.year, data.month, data.day)
time_b = DateTime.new(data.year, data.month, data.day, 23, 59, 59, 59)
Entry.all(:starttime => time_a..time_b, :order => [starttime.desc]) #=> []
```

The database contains Entries because ´Entry.all´ returns the entries.

This is a picture of an irb Session on Heroku with the loaded app.rb:
[image: irb Session on Heroku]

When i connect the PostgreSQL Database on Heroku with my local System. Everything is working!

If you want to examine the whole source code, you can find it on GitHub: https://github.com/Reflic/timekeeper

Thank you for your Help, Kevin

**Edit 1**
This is the AJAX Javascript Code:

```
function hour_chart(loading){
  if(loading){
$('#hour').html('');
  }
  $.ajax({
url: '/api/percenttoday',
type: 'GET',
data: '',
success: function(obj) {
    Morris.Donut({
        element: 'hour',
        data: [
            {label: "24h", value: obj.workpercent},
            {label: "24h", value: obj.offpercent}
        ],
        colors: ['#679DC6', '#6D6D6D'],
        formatter: function (y){return y+' %'}
    });
}
});
}
```

This is the ruby router:

```
get '/api/percenttoday' do
today_data = Stats.prepare(Stats.today(DateTime.now));

workpercent = (today_data[1].last * 100) / Dtutil::DAYSECONDS
offpercent = 100 - workpercent
json :workpercent => workpercent, :offpercent => offpercent
end
```

And here is the **Stats** Module: https://github.com/Reflic/timekeeper/blob/master/utilities.rb

Comment: You'll have to provide the `Javascript` code that send the request  and the `ruby` code that does the actual process in order for us to help out.

Comment: Btw, did you ran the `heroku run db:migrate` first?

Comment: Nope, i am not using Ruby on Rails! I am using **Sinatra** with the **datamapper** Gem. Sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: When I enter the url directly: `http://timekeper.herokuapp.com/api/percenttoday` I see a valid `json` response. Additionally, from your logs there doesn't seem to be data for today's date but the code logic (if i undertand correctly) is expecting there to be. Is that correct?

Comment: Nope, the data is there the picture is from sunday. :) Also you can put in some data your self simply fill out the pictures. Also in the picture you can see that i am using timestamps from the 17.03 and there is data of the 17.03 but is not shown.